# onclick Event refers to multiple functions

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am writing an html form. Within the code of my submit button I make references to two Javascript functions using "onclick", somehow I am not receiving the alert messages from either of them as intended. The function "notEmpty" shows alert messages if any of the form fields are empty, the function "VerifyPhoneNumber" will notify the user if the phone number entered does not adhere to the format:
XXX-XXX-XXXX. (X meaning digit)

the code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function notEmpty(elementone, elementtwo, elementthree, helperMsg){
    if(elementone.value.length == 0 || elementtwo.value.length == 0 || elementthree.value.length == 0){
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;   
    }
        return true;
    }

    function VerifyPhoneNumber(number, errormessage){
        for(int i=0; i < number.toString().length; i++){
            var space = number.substr(i,1);
                var type = isNaN(space); 
                if (type != false){
                    if (space != '-' && i != 4 && i != 8){
                        alert(errormessage);
                        elem.focus();
                        return false; 
                    }
                }
        }
        return true; 
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<p>Please input the following information:</p>

<form method="post" onSubmit="return formValidator()">

Name:
<input type="text" id="name">
Address:
<input type="text" id="address">
Phone Number:
<input type="text" id="phonenumber">
<input type="submit" onclick="notEmpty(document.getElementById('name'), document.getElementById('address'), document.getElementById('phonenumber'), 'one or more of the question fields seems to be empty'); VerifyPhoneNumber(document.getElementById('phonenumber'), 'that is not a complete phonenumber');">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Add Your Page Title here</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p>Please input the following information:</p>

<form method="post">
   Name:
   <input type="text" id="name">
   Address:
   <input type="text" id="address">
   Phone Number:
   <input type="text" id="phonenumber">
   <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit me">
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   /**
    * @param elements {Array<HTMLElement>}
    * @param helperMsg {String}
    * @returns {boolean}
    */
   function notEmpty(elements, helperMsg) {
      for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
         if (elements[i].value === '') {
            alert(helperMsg);
            elements[i].focus();
            return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }

   /**
    * @param el {Element}
    * @param errorMessage {String}
    * @returns {boolean}
    */
   function verifyPhoneNumber(el, errorMessage) {
      var regex = /^([0-9]){8}$/; //this regex pattern will match any string with at least 8 digits only
      if (!el.value.match(regex)) {
         alert(errorMessage);
         el.focus();
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

   //keep your code "DRY"
   //don't repeat yourself
   var els          = [],
       submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton"),
       names        = ['name', 'address', 'phonenumber'];

   for (var i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++) {
      els.push(document.getElementById(names[i]));
   }

   //we can now free the memory spaces housing our name array
   //since we don't need it again
   names = null;

   submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      //if this function goes through, the one below will be called
      //no need to add two event listeners
      notEmpty(els, 'one or more of the question fields seems to be empty');

      verifyPhoneNumber(els[2], 'that is not a complete phonenumber');
   });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```